# Global variables in imported modules python

Tags: python, global-variables

When global variables are all on one script, things work smoothly.

```
def foo():
  global x
  x = 'bar'
  goo()

def goo()
  global x
  print(x)

foo()
```

would print `bar` as expected.
However, it does not work when I have to import `goo` from another file, for example

`file1.py`

```
from file2 import goo

def foo():
  global x
  x = 'bar'
  goo()

foo()
```

`file2.py`

```
def goo()
  global x
  print(x)
```

results in `NameError`. How can `x` be passed to the imported function like in the first case without passing it explicitly as an argument?

Comment: Global variables are *module global*. In any case, you *shouldn't* be using global variables this way

Comment: You already mentioned it, you could explicitly pass the value as an argument to `goo`. Why don’t you want to do that?

Comment: Because I intend to use goo() in other files running in parallel and I want the global variable to be the same for all instances

Answer (score 0):

you have to set <module_name>.<variable_name> = 'bar' for it to work like so:

```
import file2

def foo():
    file2.x = 'bar'
    file2.goo()

foo()
```

file1 is the same